# Welcome screen before entering UINavigationController (Storyboard)

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I've tried to add a welcome screen to my storyboard. my main storyboard consists of a UINavigationContoller.

I have set the first page which is empty to initial view controller then had a button set to push to my UINavigation controller. Why doesn't this work?

Surely there must be a simple way of having a page before the UINavigationController.

EDIT:

I should add I need more than one image in this empty view controller and I need to animate them so a simple splash screen image wont work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, as it is shown very short but works: in your target, you can set an icon but also a load-up screen or loading screen, if you make a n image, and place it there, it will show up while loading the storyboard. I'm not sure if this will help, but I'm not that good at objective c. Good luck!

-JonanJi

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, the thing is I need to load up more than one image, animate them and have maybe some text saying touch anywhere to enter. I'm not sure if this goes against apples guidelines?